# Spark (scala) dataframes - Check whether strings in column contain any items from a set

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm pretty new to scala and spark and I've been trying to find a solution for this issue all day - it's doing my head in. I've tried 20 different variations of the following code and keep getting `type mismatch` errors when I try to perform calculations on a column.

I have a spark dataframe, and I wish to check whether each string in a particular column contains any number of words from a pre-defined `List` (or `Set`) of words.

Here is some example data for replication:

```
// sample data frame
val df = Seq(
      (1, "foo"),
      (2, "barrio"),
      (3, "gitten"),
      (4, "baa")).toDF("id", "words")

// dictionary Set of words to check 
val dict = Set("foo","bar","baaad")
```

Now, i am trying to create a third column with the results of a comparison to see if the strings in the `$"words"` column within them contain any of the words in the `dict` Set of words. So the result should be:

```
+---+-----------+-------------+
| id|      words|   word_check| 
+---+-----------+-------------+
|  1|        foo|         true|     
|  2|      bario|         true|
|  3|     gitten|        false|
|  4|        baa|        false|
+---+-----------+-------------+
```

First, I tried to see if i could do it natively without using UDFs, since the dict Set will actually be a large dictionary of > 40K words, and as I understand it this would be more efficient than a UDF:

```
df.withColumn("word_check", dict.exists(d => $"words".contains(d)))
```

But i get the error:

```
type mismatch;
found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
required: Boolean
```

I have also tried to create a UDF to do this (using both `mutable.Set` and `mutable.WrappedArray` to describe the Set - not sure which is correct but neither work):

```
val checker: ((String, scala.collection.mutable.Set[String]) => Boolean) = (col: String, array: scala.collection.mutable.Set[String] ) =>  array.exists(d => col.contains(d))

val udf1 = udf(checker)

df.withColumn("word_check", udf1($"words", dict )).show()
```

But get another type mismatch:

```
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Set[String]
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
```

If the set was a fixed number, I should be able to use `Lit(Int)` in the expression? But I don't really understand performing more complex functions on a column by mixing different data types works in scala.

Any help greatly appreciated, especially if it can be done efficiently (it is a large df of > 5m rows).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if your dict is large, you should not just reference it in your udf, because the entire dict is sent over the network for every task. I would broadcast your dict in combination with an udf:

```
import org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast

def udf_check(words: Broadcast[scala.collection.immutable.Set[String]]) = {
  udf {(s: String) => words.value.exists(s.contains(_))}
}

df.withColumn("word_check", udf_check(sparkContext.broadcast(dict))($"words"))
```

alternatively, you could also use a join:

```
val dict_df = dict.toList.toDF("word")

df
  .join(broadcast(dict_df),$"words".contains($"word"),"left")
  .withColumn("word_check",$"word".isNotNull)
  .drop($"word")
```

Comment: Question, why use the exist?  I use for word processing .filter(broadcasted.value.contains(_)). Optimization of some sort I presume.

Comment: @thebluephantom so you call `filter` on `s`, that would filter characters in `s` which are contained in the set

Comment: Actually I should say it was on a Databricks log on all the ways to do things and does work, but if the best? but my question was on exist. I am going to have a little look on your comment

Comment: isin I think is a better option

Comment: @thebluephantom no `isin` does not work here, because this wold only return `true` for exact matches of words, but it should also return true if a part of a word is contained in the dict (see the expected output in the question, e.g. for `bario`)

Comment: I checked contains is fine. Ok, got it, may be I phrased incorrectly. Cheers

Answer (score 7):

Regardless of efficiency, this seems to work:

```
df.withColumn("word_check", dict.foldLeft(lit(false))((a, b) => a || locate(b, $"words") > 0)).show

+---+------+----------+
| id| words|word_check|
+---+------+----------+
|  1|   foo|      true|
|  2|barrio|      true|
|  3|gitten|     false|
|  4|   baa|     false|
+---+------+----------+
```

Comment: This works, thank you. But in terms of efficiency it may be pretty expensive with a 40K dictionary list.

Comment: Can someone please explain this code. I am also trying to achieve something similar.

Comment: For every row it iterates over the dictionary via the foldLeft. The initial value is false, if the `locate > 0` is true, upon the next iteration `a` will be true, so it will not have to check the remainder of the dictionary

Answer (score 7):

Here's how you'd do it with a UDF:

```
val checkerUdf = udf { (s: String) => dict.exists(s.contains(_)) }

df.withColumn("word_check", checkerUdf($"words")).show()
```

The mistake in your implementation is that you've created a UDF expecting two arguments, which means you'd have to pass two `Column`s when applying it - but `dict` isn't a `Column` in your DataFrame but rather a local vairable.

Comment: dict can also be broadcasted of it's large

Comment: aha! this really clarifies things, and is a great answer, but I think I may have to go with @RaphaelRoth's suggestion as efficiency will be pretty important in this case.