# Spark (scala) - Iterate over DF column and count number of matches from a set of items

Tags: scala, apache-spark

So I can now iterate over a column of strings in a dataframe and check whether any of the strings contain any items in a large dictionary (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45442372/spark-scala-dataframes-check-whether-strings-in-column-contain-any-items-fro), thanks to @[raphael-roth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1138523/raphael-roth) and @[tzach-zohar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5344058/tzach-zohar)). The basic udf (not including broadcasting the `dict` list) for that is:

```
val checkerUdf = udf { (s: String) => dict.exists(s.contains(_)) }

df.withColumn("word_check", checkerUdf($"words")).show()
```

The next thing I am trying to do is also COUNT the number of matches that occur from the `dict` set, in the most efficient way possible (i'm dealing with very large datasets and `dict` files).

I have been trying to use findAllMatchIn in the udf, using both count and map:

```
val checkerUdf = udf { (s: String) => dict.count(_.r.findAllMatchIn(s))

// OR
val checkerUdf = udf { (s: String) => dict.map(_.r.findAllMatchIn(s))
```

But this returns a list of iterators (empty and non-empty) I get a type mismatch (found Iterator, required Boolean). I am not sure how to count the non-empty iterators (`count` and `size` and `length` don't work).

Any idea what i'm doing wrong? Is there a better / more efficient way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: why don't you just count the true from the new column?

Comment: From `dict.exists(s.contains(_))` ? That only ever returns one true for any number of occurrences.

Comment: that udf shall return you another column with matching as true and not matching as false. so you can just count the true. :) i hope you got it

Comment: but it will return a column with true/false stating if there is a match or not. I need a count (Int) of how many matches were found for each string (row), not a cont of how many true were found for the entire column.

Comment: please check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just change a little bit of the answers from your other question as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val checkerUdf = udf { (s: String) => dict.count(s.contains(_)) }

df.withColumn("word_check", checkerUdf($"words")).show()
```

Given the `dataframe` as

```
+---+---------+
|id |words    |
+---+---------+
|1  |foo      |
|2  |barriofoo|
|3  |gitten   |
|4  |baa      |
+---+---------+
```

and dict file as

```
val dict = Set("foo","bar","baaad")
```

You should have output as

```
+---+---------+----------+
| id|    words|word_check|
+---+---------+----------+
|  1|      foo|         1|
|  2|barriofoo|         2|
|  3|   gitten|         0|
|  4|      baa|         0|
+---+---------+----------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: great to hear that @renegademonkey :) thanks for the acceptance and an upvote :)