# Spark job running without result for long

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two dataframes with about a million records each, I'm looking to append True or false to each row on df1 bases on a column partial match with the column in the other df.

I have considered writing a UDF and then compare strings from both columns but it doesn't work

```
var df1 = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "\t").load("hdfs://XXXXX.txt")   
var df2 = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "\t").load("YYYYYYY.txt")

var desc =df2.select("SHORT_DESC").map(_.getString(0)).collect.toList
var desc_str  = desc.mkString(" ")

def matchBoth(s:String ,s1: String) : Boolean ={ 
  if(s1.contains(s)) true
  else false
}

var contains = udf(matchBoth _)    

var df3=df1.withColumn("flag",contains(lower($"Col45"),lit(desc_str.toLowerCase)))
```

Comment: How large is your dataset, and what is "for long"? Are you getting a result back?

Comment: my dataset has 2 million records, I wasn't getting any result earlier. Gorros suggestion worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think your use-case is quite similar to [this](http://httpshttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/45442372/spark-scala-dataframes-check-whether-strings-in-column-contain-any-items-fro) one, where there is initially a set of values. In your case you already have dataframe, so you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45443850/4390959) answer and join your dataframes. Which should result in following (please recheck yourself):

```
df1
.join(broadcast(df2.select("SHORT_DESC")),$"Col45".contains($"SHORT_DESC"),"left")
.withColumn("flag",$"SHORT_DESC".isNotNull)
.drop($"SHORT_DESC")
```